# Remove records from Deployment Status

Tags: sccm

We're running a chain of updates and installs via a Task Sequence, SCCM 2012 R2 and a mix of 7 and 10 labs.  Some of the stations reported success in one deployment I made, others are reporting success in a deployment my coworker made (we were both testing at the same time and didn't communicate well enough).

While the machines have been removed from the deployment, Deployment Status still reports them in one deployment or the other.  We'd like to remove the stations that Errored in one group, as they're reporting as Success in the other.

Is there any way to remove records from a Deployment Status for a collection in Monitoring?

I've been unsuccessful in my searches, won't be surprised if the answer is no, and sorry if this is a duplicate, I searched before asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to clear out status messages from sccm for a given period but not for specific systems that i know of. SCCM probably saves these in the database, You could try to delete them from there.